# Docker User Defined networks - How to create multi-level Docker network hierarchy

Tags: docker, networking, subnet, docker-network

I want to create a multi-level docker network like:

[image: this].

The outer network is 192.168.0.0/16. It has two subnets - 192.168.1.0/24 and 192.168.2.0/24.

Containers in different subnets must be able to communicate with each other (192.168.1.10 should be able to speak to 192.168.2.10).

The entire setup is on a single host (wasn't sure if i should be using overlay networks).

I followed this [guide](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/work-with-networks/#connect-containers) which shows how to create subnets and create containers in those subnets, but I couldn't find anything on creating a network hierarchy.

Comment: Are you expecting to be able to connect the container networks from outside the host as well?

Comment: @Matt No i just want inter-subnet commutation from within the host.